# $f$ is bounded, continuous monotone function and therefore is uniform continuous (Proof verifying).

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f$ be bounded, monotone and continuous on $\Bbb{R}$. Prove $f$ is uniformly continuous.
I mostly need a proof verification so that I know what I am doing is either correct or incorrect.

$Attempt:$ A bounded, monotone and continuous function has its limits $\lim_\limits{x\to \infty}f(x)=L_1,\lim_\limits{x\to -\infty}f(x)=L_2$. Let us look at $[0,\infty)$. Let $\epsilon>0$. I shall find $\delta>0$ such that $\forall x,y\in [0,\infty), |x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. There exists $M>0$ such that $\forall x\ge M$, $|f(x)-L_1|<{\epsilon\over 2}.$ For $x,y\in [0,M]$ there is $\delta_1$ such that $|x-y|<\delta_1\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<{\epsilon\over 2}$. Since $\forall x,y\in [M,\infty), |f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x)-L_1+L_1-f(y)|\le |f(x)-L_1|+|f(y)-L_1|<\epsilon$ then for $x,y\in[M,\infty)$ the vicinity is of infinite length, therefore I should by now take the vicinity that holds for both cases: $\delta_1$. Now let $x,y\in [0,\infty), \text{such that } |x-y|<\delta_1$. Either $x,y\in [0,M]$ and then $|f(x)-f(y)|<{\epsilon\over 2}<\epsilon$, or $x,y\ge M$ and then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$, **or**, WLOG, $x\in [0,M], y\in [M,\infty)$ and then $|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x)-f(M)+f(M)+f(y)|\le |f(x)-f(M)|+|f(y)-f(M)|$.

Since $x,M\in [0,M]$ and $|x-M|<\delta_1$ then $|f(x)-f(M)|<{\epsilon \over 2}$. Since $M,y\ge M$ then $|f(y)-f(M)|<{\epsilon\over 2}$. That is, $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: What is your notation $U^*_{\delta_1} (L_1)$?

Comment: A punctured vicinity $(L_1-\delta_1, L_1+\delta_1)$ I should have made it clear, I am sorry...

Comment: So if $x$ is closed to $L_1$, how will $|f(x) - L_1|$ be small? $x$ is "in the $x$ axis" while $f(x)$ and $L_1$ are on $y$-axis..

Comment: Well, I used Cauchy's definition of a limit, saying that $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists \delta$ such that $\forall x\in U^*_{\delta} (L)$, $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$...

Comment: That would be correct if the limit of f(x) as x approaches $L_1$ were $L_1$, but in this case $L_1$ is the limit of f(x) as x approaches infinity.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: So do you know the definition for $\lim_{x\to +\infty}  \ f(x) = L_1$?

Comment: $\exists M>0$ such that $\forall x>M$, $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$?

Comment: More or less: $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists M>0$ such that ..... You may try to do that using this definition and edit your question. Then we may come back to see if that is correct.

Comment: Okay, I try now. :)

Comment: Can you use that f restricted to a compact domain is uniformly continuous?

Comment: Yes. This is why I partition $[0,\infty)$...

Comment: Okey, but be careful that $[0,\infty)$ is not compact, $[0,M]$ for any real M is.

Comment: Thank you, that is why I do partition...

Comment: I finished. If you would like to take a look, that would really help me...

Comment: That looks good to me.